# What are $c$'s in antiderivative of double integral in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha, symbolic-computation, bivariate-distributions

I would like to solve the following double integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x y)^{-\theta - 1} dx \hspace{1mm} dy$$

Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20integral%20%28x%20y%29%5E%28-t-1%29%20dx%20dy) for symbolic algebra, it gives a solution of
$$=c_1 x + c_2 + \frac{(x y)^{-\theta}}{\theta^2}$$

but what are the $c$'s and where did they come from? are they complex numbers, or [constants of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration)? am I allowed to set them to $0$?

What solution would a derivation by hand result in?

Comment: what is your definition of $(xy)^{-\theta-1}$ when $xy<0$ and $-\theta-1$ is not an integer?

Comment: the double integral shown is actually a component of a larger integration problem I'm struggling with, which actually restricts $x$ and $y$ to be $[0,1]$, and $\theta \in [-1,\infty)$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829062/analytical-closed-form-solution-for-the-entropy-of-a-parametric-copula

Comment: ok. It doesn't seem related or relevant to consider the integral on $x,y<0$ IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in fact constants of integration as mentioned by md2perpe.

When you substitute the limits, the integral diverges (as can be seen from [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20integral%20%28x%20y%29%5E%28-t-1%29%20dx%20dy%20from%20x%3D-infinity%20to%20x%3Dinfinity%2C%20from%20y%3D-infinity%20to%20y%3Dinfinity)).

To compute the indefinite integral we have:

$$\int \int (xy)^{-\theta-1} dx dy=\int \int (xy)^{-\theta-1} dy dx$$
$$=\int \int x^{-\theta-1} y^{-\theta-1} dydx$$
$$=\int [-x^{-\theta-1}\frac{y^{-\theta}}{\theta}+c_{1}]dx$$
$$=\frac{x^{-\theta}y^{-\theta}}{\theta^2}+c_{1}x+c_{2}=c_{1}x+c_{2}+\frac{(xy)^{-\theta}}{\theta^2}.$$

Also note that you can have $$\int \int (xy)^{-\theta-1} dx dy=c_{1}y+c_{2}+\frac{(xy)^{-\theta}}{\theta^2}$$ due to symmetry.

Comment: i wasn't sure how to express this with double integral signs, but the question is actually a second mixed partial derivative, first w.r.t. $x$, and then w.r.t. $y$. Does this change the solution and divergence property?

Comment: If you had partial derivatives $\partial x \partial y$, then after the first integration, instead of constants we would have functions of $x$ and $y$. Since clearly   $\frac{(xy)^{-\theta}}{\theta^2}$ disappears when you put the limits, it will depend on the functions of $x$ and $y$ if the integral diverges. In the case above, the integral diverges since the term $c_{1}y$ or $c_{1}x$ diverges.

Comment: thanks. how could I have indicated that the double integral was in fact a second mixed partial derivative? are there partial $\int \int$ signs? replace $dx dy$ with $\partial x \partial y$ in the same formula?

Comment: Yeah you would write $\int \int \partial x \partial y$.

Answer (score 2):

They are constants of integration. You get them because you don't haven't given WolframAlpha the limits of your integral.