# How can I approximate $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{7/6}\ln(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}})dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation

My approximation here needs to be valid for large values of $x$ here.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{7/6}\ln\Bigg(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\Bigg)dx$$
I can't seem to get around this natural log no matter what I do. How can this integral be approximated without going to $0$? I know there is a solution in an integral table if the natural log wasn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very simple way to get rid of the logarithm: integration by parts. So we have
$$\int^\infty_0x^a\ln\left(\frac1{1-e^{-x}}\right)\,dx=\frac1{a+1}\int^\infty_0x^{a+1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx.$$ The fraction can be written as a geometric series:
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}e^{-kx},$$ and since it's a positive series, we can exchange summation and integral:
$$\int^\infty_0x^{a+1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\int^\infty_0x^{a+1}e^{-kx}\,dx.$$ Substituting $kx=t$, we see that
$$\int^\infty_0x^{a+1}e^{-kx}\,dx=\frac1{k^{a+2}}\int^\infty_0t^{a+1}e^{-t}\,dt=\frac{\Gamma(a+2)}{k^{a+2}},$$ using the well-known integral representation of the Gamma function. So our integral becomes
$$\int^\infty_0x^{a+1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx=\Gamma(a+2)\,\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac1{k^{a+2}}=\Gamma(a+2)\,\zeta(a+2).$$ Putting all of that together, we obtain
$$\int^\infty_0x^a\ln\left(\frac1{1-e^{-x}}\right)\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(a+2)\,\zeta(a+2)}{a+1}=\Gamma(a+1)\,\zeta(a+2)$$ (many thanks to @Gary for the last simplification).

For $a=7/6$, that's approximately $1.2686090974543140685705195862758272411$.

Comment: Note that $\Gamma(a+2)/(a+1)=\Gamma(a+1)$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector could you also answer this question using integration of parts, also containing an integrated logarithm and the t-distribution's Gamma function: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840404/analytical-closed-form-solution-for-the-entropy-of-student-t-copula

Answer (score 4):

*This is not a full answer.*

Considering
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{(1+a)}\log\Bigg(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\Bigg)\,dx $$ by Taylor
$$I(a)=\zeta (3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty} x \log ^n(x)\log\Bigg(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\Bigg)\,dx $$

The remaining integrals

$$J_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} x \log ^n(x)\log\Bigg(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\Bigg)\,dx$$
do not show closed form but they can be tabulated and, as long as $a$ is small, the summation *seems* to converge quite fast. Summing up to $p$, for $a=\frac 16$ the results would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 1.253737667 \\
 2 & 1.268492231 \\
 3 & 1.268514471 \\
 4 & 1.268612760 \\
 5 & 1.268608473 \\
 6 & 1.268609145 \\
 7 & 1.268609093 \\
 8 & 1.268609098 \\
 9 & 1.268609097 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Tested for $a=\frac 13$, we have the same kind of convergence
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 1.305418432 \\
 2 & 1.364436687 \\
 3 & 1.364614603 \\
 4 & 1.366187225 \\
 5 & 1.366050056 \\
 6 & 1.366093078 \\
 7 & 1.366086316 \\
 8 & 1.366087690 \\
 9 & 1.366087444 \\
 10 & 1.366087490 \\
 11 & 1.366087481 \\
 12 & 1.366087483 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: here is a similar log-integration problem to derive https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840404/analytical-closed-form-solution-for-the-entropy-of-student-t-copula

Answer (score 3):

If we use the Maclaurin series of the logarithm, we obtain that the integral is
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{ + \infty } {x^{7/6} e^{ - nx} dx} }  = \Gamma \left( {2 + \tfrac{1}{6}} \right)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{3 + 1/6} }}}  = \Gamma \left( {2 + \tfrac{1}{6}} \right)\zeta \left( {3 + \tfrac{1}{6}} \right),
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.