# Integration by parts $3n$ times.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

I found the equation below in [Repeated integration by parts of a definite integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532817/repeated-integration-by-parts-of-a-definite-integral)

\begin{align}
\int_a^b f^{(n)}(x)g(x) dx = (-1)^{(n)}\int_a^b f(x)g^{(n)}(x) dx
\end{align}

which is true if $\left.f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x)\right|_a^b=0 \: \forall k \in [0:n-1]$

So I want to test on the integral below:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{d^{3n}}{dx^{3n}} (x^3-x^4)^n e^x dx 
\end{align}

here $f(x) = (x^3-x^4)^n$ and $g(x)=e^x$.

Is the following correct?

\begin{align}
&\int_a^b f^{(3n)}(x)g(x) dx = (-1)^{(3n)}\int_a^b f(x)g^{(3n)}(x) dx\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{d^{3n}}{dx^{3n}} (x^3-x^4)^n e^x dx = 
(-1)^{(3n)} \int_0^1 (x^3-x^4)^n e^x dx
\end{align}

if not, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The formula is applicable because when you differentiate $f$ $k$ times with $k <n$ there  will be at least one factor of $x^{3}-x^{4}$ left in each term and $x^{3}-x^{4}=0$ for $x=0$ and $x=1$.